# Qt Drag&Drop from QTableWidget to folder

Tags: c++, qt, drag-and-drop, qt5

I have custom QTableWidget, how i can make Drag&Drop from table indexes to folder? I have have QList collection with archive files.
This code works perfect for drop to application

```
void ArchiveQTableWidget::keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent *event)
{
    if (event->key() == Qt::Key_Return && currentRow() > -1)
        enterClicked(currentIndex());
    QTableWidget::keyPressEvent(event);
}

void ArchiveQTableWidget::dragEnterEvent(QDragEnterEvent *event)
{
    if (event->mimeData()->hasUrls()) {
        event->acceptProposedAction();
    }
}

void ArchiveQTableWidget::dragMoveEvent(QDragMoveEvent *event)
{
    event->acceptProposedAction();
}

void ArchiveQTableWidget::dragLeaveEvent(QDragLeaveEvent *event)
{
    event->accept();
}

void ArchiveQTableWidget::dropEvent(QDropEvent *event)
{
    foreach (const QUrl &url, event->mimeData()->urls()) {
        QString fileName = url.toLocalFile();
        qDebug() << "Dropped file:" << fileName;
    }
}

void ArchiveQTableWidget::startDrag(Qt::DropActions supportedActions)
{
    StreamQMimeData mimeData = new StreamQMimeData;
    connect(mimeData, SIGNAL(dataRequested(QString)),
            this, SLOT(createData(QString)), Qt::DirectConnection);
    QDrag *drag = new QDrag(this);
    drag->setMimeData(mimeData);
    drag->exec(Qt::CopyAction);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to call `QMimeData::setUrls( QList<QUrl> )`.